# Difference between property initializer and init() function

Tags: swift, swiftui

Basically I want to create two properties where one is dependent on the other. I find that if I try to initialize the dependent property in this manner, it doesn't work.

```swift
class Bus {
    private let driverList = ["A", "B", "C"]
    private var driver: String = driverList.randomElement()!
    @Published private var bus: String = createBus(driver: driver)
    
    static func createBus(driver: String) -> String {
        return "Bus with driver \(driver)"
    }
}
```

I get "Cannot use instance member 'driver' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" error message. What I understand is that `self` is still not available since all of the class members haven't been initialzed yet. However, when I put it inside `init()` like it, it works.

```swift
class Bus {
    private let driverList = ["A", "B", "C"]
    private var driver: String = driverList.randomElement()!
    @Published private var bus: String
    
    init() {
        self.bus = Bus.createBus(driver: driver)
    }

    static func createBus(driver: String) -> String {
        return "Bus with driver \(driver)"
    }
}
```

As a result, I wonder if `init()` behaves similarly to `lazy` or it is called directly after `self` is available which is confusing since all of the members still haven't been initialized so how come `init()` has access to `self`.

Edit: I moved the array inside the class and I actually have @Published for `bus` property because I want to monitor the changes and update in the view. I find that having @Published makes things more complicated. My apology for not including in the first place since I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: Just make `bus` lazy

Comment: *Basically* declaring an array outside of a class or struct is very bad practice.

Comment: my use case is actually @Published for ```bus``` and using lazy and @Published together is not allowed

Comment: I will edit the question to include @Published and move the array

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html), the `init()` function prepares a class for use / creates a new instance of it.

In the sense, the class doesn't exist until `init()` is called, meaning you cannot access the variable `driver` until you initialize the class. Since `init()` *initializes* the class, it creates the `self` you can use.

Comment: I am still confused why you cannot initialize it inline instead.